# C# Checking expiry of user issue

Tags: c#

Hey guys I'm trying to making a license based application
And I'm using, string Userinfo.Expiry for Expiry
now I want to check user expiration status every 2000ms, I did it but I can't compare

```
Userinfo.Expiry > Datetime.Now.ToString()
```

Results in `Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'`

Value of User Expiry is a date and I'm using Visual Studio C# Latest Forms

What can I do about this issue?

Comment: Have you tried converting Userinfo.Expiry to a DateTime and then comparing that value to Datetime.Now?

Comment: What did you try? What framework do you use? What's the value of `Userinfo`?

Comment: There are plenty of questions on comparing strings and dates... So far it is very unclear what you hope to achieve with `Userinfo.Expiry > Datetime.Now.ToString()` as `DateTime.ToString()` does not return string that can be safely compare with another date (you'd need "O" format for that).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Strings cannot be compared at all (using `<`), and it appears that `Userinfo.Expiry` is a string

Comment: @ChayimFriedman unbelivable. There is no way to compare strings? Try Google or Bing  https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+compare+strings I don't know what search engine you use to find information... avoid Netflix and Disney for programming questions. I mean Disney have some prgramming too... like TV programming :)

Comment: You can, but not using operators

Comment: `string.Compare()` is a good start. I believe that because string comparison is so hard (case sensitive? what to do with numbers, for instance, is `"9" < "10"`?) it is available only through (overloaded) methods

Comment: Reb @ChayimFriedman it is more likely that saying things like "more than" and "less than" don't make semantic sense with strings, and causes confusion (re numbers in strings). Whereas saying `CompareTo` just means they have a deterministic ordering, phone-book style.

Comment: Since you are new here, here's some advice.  First, as just about everyone has pointed out, you need to include enough code so that the reader can understand the error.  In this case, you really needed to show the type of `UserInfo.Expiry` (you could show the entire type of UserInfo (unless it's really long)).  Second, your title isn't useful. What you are trying to do (from our eyes) is compare two dates.  Third, you should format code as code.  Notice the edited version is easier to read.  Finally (most importantly), a simple search for _"c# compare dates"_ would have turned up several links

Comment: I'm sorry, everyone.
That's my first post and I just wanted to get my issue answer.
I will not do the same bad title etc.

Comment: Alright, we're all learning. But please edit the question to eliminate the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your exception it appears that UserInfo.Expiry is a string and you are trying to put a arithmetic comparison on string. What you need to do is to convert the property Expiry to datetime.

Check out DateTime.Parse https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0

If there are chances it could be any other value than a proper datetime, then use DateTime.TryParse

Once you convert it to datetime, then you can use ">" to the value and DateTime.Now or use  DateTime.Subtract